# Table-Valued Parameters not visible

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-valued-parameters

For a reason unknown to me, I cannot access the contents of my TVP. The debugger says @_AccountList and @AccountTVP are tables, but I cannot view the contents, print them, nor will intellisense offer me auto completion for a column. I feel like probably declared something wrong or have an ambiguous definition. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TYPE AccountList
AS TABLE
(
    AccountNumber varchar(50),
    AccountType varchar(50)
) 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateNumbers_ArchiveDB]
 @_AccountList AccountList READONLY,
 @padding int,
 @proc_dateStart datetime,
 @proc_dateEnd datetime
 AS 

 DECLARE @AccountTVP AS AccountList;

 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM @AccountTVP;


 UPDATE dbo.Archive2007001 
    SET LogicalAccount = @padding + AccountNumber
    FROM dbo.Archive2007001 INNER JOIN @AccountTVP AS tvp
    ON dbo.Archive2007001.LogicalAccount = tvp.AccountNumber
    WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN @proc_dateStart AND @proc_dateEnd

 UPDATE dbo.DailyArchive 
    SET LogicalAccount = @padding + AccountNumber
    FROM dbo.DailyArchive INNER JOIN @AccountTVP AS tvp
    ON dbo.DailyArchive.LogicalAccount = tvp.AccountNumber
    WHERE ProcessDate BETWEEN @proc_dateStart AND @proc_dateEnd


 -- does not work PRINT N'tvp.AccountNumber is ' + @AccountTVP.AccountNumber

 END
```

Here is how I am executing the procedure.

```
declare @p1 dbo.AccountList
insert into @p1 values(N'Account Number',N'Account Type')
insert into @p1 values(N'7463689',N'Basic')
insert into @p1 values(N'1317893',N'Premium')
insert into @p1 values(N'2806127',N'Basic')

exec updateNumbers_ArchiveDB 
@_AccountList=@p1,
@padding=N'111',
@proc_dateStart='2008-01-04 11:24:46',
@proc_dateEnd='2008-01-04 11:24:46'
```

Answer: The data I was looking for was loaded in `@_AccountList`, not `@AccountTVP`.

Comment: But @AccountTVP is empty.  @_AccountList is what is passed to the procedure.

Comment: Ya, I figured that out. Strange, I could have sworn I tried accessing @_AccountList as well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And that is what your first answer told you

Answer (score 2):

`@AccountTVP.AccountNumber` represents a row of data, not a single value, so trying to print it will not work.

You should be able to see the incoming values by using a SELECT statement:

`SELECT * FROM @_AccountList;`

It seems like your SELECT statement from the top of the stored procedure should let you see the values, however, you have not actually set any values in `@AccountTVP` so it would be empty.

I am not sure but I suspect the debugger may not work because `AccountList` is a custom type.

Comment: Edited the OP with how I am executing the procedure. I feel the select statement should work as well. Is there a way I can print just a single value from @AccountTVP?

Comment: ```@AccountTVP``` is going to be empty, you never insert any data into it.  But if you wanted to get a single value, you could ```SELECT TOP 1 AccountNumber FROM @AccountTVP```